# cefsharp изменить передаваемую информацию об экране

Tags: c#, webbrowser, cefsharp

Добрый день, возможно ли изменить информацию, которую передает браузер сайту ? а именно разрешение экрана ? я попытался так, но не сработало

```
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("Screen-width", "600");
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("Screen-height", "800");
Cef.Initialize(settings);
chromeBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("http://ipleak.net/");
```

Comment: Столкнулся с аналогичной проблемой. Вам удалось найти решение?

Comment: @maxwell нет, я перешел на firefox, а там уже программно изменил